# How to remotely restart a Linux server without SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-access, ubuntu-14.04, vnc

I have a Hummingboard running Ubuntu 14.04 which I use to work remotely on my coding projects. Sometimes I cannot connect using SSH or VNC and I have to physically unplug and replug it. Is there a way to do this process remotely?

Comment: Are you looking for hw or sw solution?

Comment: Software would be better

Comment: i don't think that a sw solution exists: if i was able to turn on/off a server without authentication it means that i'm god :D

Comment: What kind of hw solution then?

Comment: A friend told me about a hw that do this.. i try to ask him and then i will refer you!

Comment: When you say remotely, is it in a different physical location?  Or do you just mean that it is headless (no keyboard or screen) and so you have to use the keyboard/screen from another system?

Comment: if SSH and VNC aren't working, then presumably either your network stack has crashed and no other type of connection will work over the network either, or the server has crashed completely.  In the former case, you could potentially connect over some other interface, like USB, at least if the system is in the same room with you.  Maybe you could add a mini PCIe serial port card.  The Hummingboard also has an Infrared Receiver that might be able to be used.

Answer (score 0):

For example if you have ibm server you can look for something like [that](http://www.ebay.com/itm/IBM-NETFINITY-ADVANCED-SYSTEM-MANAGEMENT-PCI-ADAPTER-OPT-01K7209-24P6538-/301317787039?nma=true&si=tB6t9kyoayPqRAXeC73X%252FoErfLg%253D&orig_cvip=true&rt=nc&_trksid=p2047675.l2557)

Or other solution like [this](http://www.amazon.it/Aviosys-9258S-Remote-Power-Switch/dp/B004O1XZVW/) or [this](http://www.amazon.it/Value-Remote-Switch-Socket-4-way/dp/B006N4PUDE/)